# If $x_{n+1}=x_n+(-1)^n a_{n+1}$. Is $\{x_n\}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

This problem still poses some challenge. Since $a_n$ is an alternating term, I wouldn't know I to go about it. The question is, if $a_n>0,a_{n+1}<a_n, \;a_n\to 0.$ Define 
$$x_1=a_1\;\; \text{and}\;\; x_{n+1}=x_n+(-1)^n a_{n+1}.\;\;\;\;(*)$$

Is $\{x_n\}$ convergent? Below is a useful hint:

Since $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ is complete, it is sufficient to prove that $\Bbb{R}$ is Cauchy. Also, I am required to use the conditions $a_n>0,a_{n+1}<a_n, \;a_n\to 0$ and the term $(-1)^n a_{n+1}$. So, rewriting $(*)$ we get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_{n+1}.  \;\;\;\;(**)$$

I want to use the alternating series test to obtain that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ converges. Also, letting $m,n\in\Bbb{N}$ with $n>m,$ I am to use $(**)$ to prove that $|x_n-x_m|\to 0\;\;\text{as}\;\;n\to \infty.$

Comment: Yes, it is. This is the same point as in the Leibniz series.

Comment: Sorry but what is there left to do? Please be precise.

Comment: @ Did: I want to show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. Since this hint was provided. So, I need help in proving that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy and hence, convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_n =x_1 +\sum_{k=2}^n (x_k -x_{k-1} ) =a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^n (-1)^{k-1} a_k =\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} a_k\to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} a_k$
by Leibnitz Test.